# PHP LDAP connection

Tags: php, ldap

I have this class, which helps me to connect to LDAP:

```
    class adUser {

        private $_username;
        private $_password;

        public function __construct($username, $password)
        { 
          $this->_username = $username;
          $this->_password = $password;
        }

        public function connectAD() 
        {

            # Connect to Domain Controller
            $ldap = ldap_connect("censored");

            # Case / When to see if user and password match
            if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $this->_username, $this->_password)) 
                {
                  # todo: Successful
                  return $this->_username;
                } 
            else 
                {
                  # todo: Failure
                  echo "Invalid login.";
                  header('Location: index.php?eid=1');
                }

            # Close connection
            ldap_close($ldap);
        }

        public function getFullName()
        {

            # Initialize the connection
            $ldap = ldap_connect("censored");
            ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

            # Parameters bound
            $dn = "censored";
            $bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $this->_username, $this->_password);

            # Will trim domain and slash from username 
            $person = substr($this->_username,strpos($this->_username,"\\")+1,strlen($this->_username) - strpos($this->_username,"\\"));

            # Set search criteria (search on username -> return cn aka full name)
            $filter="(sAMAccountName=".$person.")";
            $justthese = array("cn");
            $sr=ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);

            # Loop through results - although we only have one entry at this time.
            for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
                        //echo "dn is: ". $data[$i]["dn"] ."<br />";
                         echo $info[$i]["cn"][0];
                    }

            # Close the connection
            ldap_close($ldap);
        }
    }
```

It's basically the second time I've tried OOP PHP - is there any way where I could significantly compress this class? Did I get this whole OOP thing right?

This is how I call the functions:

```
include_once("functions/LDAP.php");

$curUser = new adUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

echo "logged in as: ".$curUser->connectAD();
echo "<br>";

$curUser->getFullName();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've commented through your existing code below and noted what was removed/replaced/added (my comments are denoted by double `#`'s):

```
## Let's modify the class name 'adUser' to something more 
## informative, like 'ActiveDirectoryUser'
class ActiveDirectoryUser {
    private $connection;

    ## The use of an underscore is a leftover from a past convention
    ## it is ok to not have an underscore on private properties
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $ldap_db = "censored";
    private $ldap_connection; ## We moved the connection to here for state\

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password) {
      $this->username = $username;
      $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */
    public function __destruct(){
        ldap_close($this->ldap_connection);
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */

    ## We'll rename connectAD to connect - it should be simple.
    public function connect() {
        ## Get rid of this comment - it doesn't tell us anything informative
        # Connect to Domain Controller
        $this->ldap_connection = ldap_connect($this->ldap_db); ## Replaced the string with a property for reuse

        ## Again with the uninformative comment - it 
        ## doesn't tell us anything that the code already does
        # Case / When to see if user and password match
        if ($bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password)) {
            ## We'll return true if it connects, otherwise throw an exception. 
            ## Our connect() function shouldn't ever return a username or data
            return True
            # return $this->username;

        # Your bracketing in else is weird and unconventional
        } else {
          # todo: Failure
          #echo "Invalid login.";

          # Don't handle your redirect logic in your class - do so at call level
          # Instead, throw an exception or return False
          #header('Location: index.php?eid=1');
          throw new Exception("Invalid login.");
        }

        ## Why are we closing the connection in the connect function? Move this to the destruct()
        # Close connection
        #ldap_close($ldap);
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */

    ## Renamed from getFullName to getName
    public function getName(){
        # Initialize the connection
        ## No need to call LDAP connection again since we already have the connection stored in a property
        # $ldap = ldap_connect($this->ldap_db);
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        # Parameters bound
        $bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password);

        # Will trim domain and slash from username 
        $person = substr($this->username,strpos($this->username,"\\")+1,strlen($this->username) - strpos($this->username,"\\"));

        # Set search criteria (search on username -> return cn aka full name)
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=".$person.")";

        ## justthese can be moved to the ldap_search function since its inline and only called once
        ## additionally, we can use the shorthand [] array initiator
        #$justthese = array("cn");
        $sr = ldap_search($this->ldap_connection, $this->ldap_db, $filter, ['cn']);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);

        # Loop through results - although we only have one entry at this time.
        ## We'll have a returnData array to return rather than echo out.
        $returnData = [];
        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
            //echo "dn is: ". $data[$i]["dn"] ."<br />";
            $returnData[] = $info[$i]["cn"][0];
        }

        ## Don't need to close it as it's closed on class destruct
        # Close the connection
        #ldap_close($ldap);

        return $returnData;
    }
}
```

and here is the same, with my comments removed:

```
/**
 * Always have documentation here
 */
class ActiveDirectoryUser {
    private $connection;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $ldap_db = "censored";
    private $ldap_connection;

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password) {
      $this->username = $username;
      $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */
    public function __destruct(){
        ldap_close($this->ldap_connection);
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation 
     * @param $username string
     * @param $password string
     */

    public function connect() {
        $this->ldap_connection = ldap_connect($this->ldap_db);

        if ($bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password)) {
            return True
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid login.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Always have documentation
     */
    public function getName(){
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($this->ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        $bind = ldap_bind($this->ldap_connection, $this->username, $this->password);

        # Will trim domain and slash from username 
        $person = substr($this->username, strpos($this->username, "\\") + 1,
                         strlen($this->username) - strpos($this->username,"\\"));

        $filter="(sAMAccountName=" . $person.")";

        $sr = ldap_search($this->ldap_connection, $this->ldap_db, $filter, ['cn']);
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);

        $returnData = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
            $returnData[] = $info[$i]["cn"][0];
        }

        return $returnData;
    }
}
```

And finally, the usage (note we have to try/catch for Exception):

```
include_once("functions/LDAP.php");

$ActiveDirectoryUser = new ActiveDirectoryUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
try{
    $ActiveDirectoryUser->connect();
} catch (Exception $e){
    # Do header redirect here
}

$user = $ActiveDirectoryUser->getName();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's quite a new level for me. I've just went it through, will spend some time on it to better understand. One question though: "always have documentation" what should be put in there? A basic description of the function, and what the arguments are for?

Comment: A basic description of the function, as well as any parameters it takes, and what it returns at the very least. Take a look at my PHPBenchTime library to see comments: https://github.com/jsanc623/PHPBenchTime/blob/master/src/Timer.php as well as the PHPDoc wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc